# Trust region sub-problem with Jacobi Condition

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the $2 \times 2$ trust region sub-problem. Given $Q$ symmetric $2 \times 2$, vector $\mathbf b$ and $\Delta > 0$, find $\mathbf x$ that minimizes $f(x)=\frac {1}{2} \mathbf x^T Q \mathbf x - \mathbf b^T \mathbf x$ over $\mathbf x$ satisfying $||\mathbf x||_{2}^{2} \leq \Delta$. We can use the necessary conditions: there is a $\lambda \geq 0$ where

$Q + \lambda I$ is positive semi-definite

$(Q + \lambda I)\mathbf x=\mathbf b$

either $\lambda =0$ or $||\mathbf x||_{2} =\Delta$

Use the Jacobi conditions to find the $\lambda$ for which $Q + \lambda I$ is positive definite.

(These conditions are that $q_{11} + \lambda > 0$ and det$(Q + \lambda I >0$)

Then find the minimum value of $\lambda \geq 0$ for which $Q + \lambda I$ is positive semi-definite.

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem and any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I do know that a matrix B is positive semi-definite if and only if $B+\epsilon I$ is positive definite for all $\epsilon>)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question but I am assuming you want to solve the trust region problem?

---

\begin{align}
\min_x\qquad & \frac{1}{2}x^TQx-b^Tx\\s.t.\qquad &x^Tx\leq \Delta\\
\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)&=\frac{1}{2}x^TQx-b^Tx- \lambda(\Delta-x^Tx)\\
\nabla_x\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)&=Qx-b+ 2\lambda x=0\\
b&=(Q+2\lambda I)x\\
x&=(Q+2\lambda I)^{-1}b\\
\end{align}
Now,

**Case 1:**

$x^Tx<\Delta$, $\lambda=0$ and $x=Q^{-1}b$ which can be the solution only if $x^Tx<\Delta$.

**Case 2:**

If $x^Tx=\Delta$, then $\lambda$ can be found as a solution to:
$$x^Tx=\Delta$$ where $x=(Q+2\lambda I)^{-1}b$

This is a valid solution only if $\lambda \geq 0$